# UIAccelerometer issue with landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uiaccelerometer

I am using `UIAccelerometer` in my game and it is working fine in portrait mode but not working properly in landscape mode.

Can some one fix the issue in my code

I am putting my code as below:

```
#import "GameLayer.h"


@implementation GameLayer


+(id)scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    CCLayer *layer = [GameLayer node];
    [scene addChild:layer];

    return scene;
}

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;

        player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spaceship.png"];
        [self addChild:player];

        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        player.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);

        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }

    return self; 
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    float deceleration = 1.0f;
    float maxVelocity = 50;

    playerVelocity.x = playerVelocity.x * deceleration + acceleration.x;
    playerVelocity.y = playerVelocity.y * deceleration + acceleration.y;

    if (playerVelocity.x > maxVelocity)
    {
        playerVelocity.x = maxVelocity;
    }
    else if (playerVelocity.x < -maxVelocity)
    {
        playerVelocity.x = -maxVelocity;
    }


    if (playerVelocity.y > maxVelocity)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = maxVelocity;
    }
    else if (playerVelocity.y < -maxVelocity)
    { 
        playerVelocity.y = -maxVelocity; 
    } 
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)delta
{
    CGPoint pos = player.position; pos.x += playerVelocity.x;
    pos.y += playerVelocity.y;

    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    float imageWidthHalved = player.texture.contentSize.width * 0.5f;
    float imageHeightHalved = player.texture.contentSize.height * 0.5f;

    float leftBorderLimit = imageWidthHalved;
    float rightBorderLimit = screenSize.width - imageWidthHalved;
    float topBorderLimit = imageHeightHalved;
    float bottomBorderLimit = screenSize.height - imageHeightHalved;

    if (pos.x < leftBorderLimit)
    {
        pos.x = leftBorderLimit;
        playerVelocity.x = 0;
    }
    else if (pos.x > rightBorderLimit)
    {
        pos.x = rightBorderLimit;
        playerVelocity.x = 0;
    }

    if (pos.y < topBorderLimit)
    {
        pos.y = topBorderLimit;
        playerVelocity.y = 0; }
    else if (pos.y > bottomBorderLimit)
    {
        pos.y = bottomBorderLimit;
        playerVelocity.y = 0; 
    }

    player.position = pos; 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accelerometer axes do not change with change in orientation. You will have to handle the different orientation cases in your `- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration` method by detecting the current device orientation.

Comment: What change I need to do with my code. May you please make the changes. My app is only for landscape... So I no need to check the orientation..... I coppied this code from internet. But it seem this is for portrait mode as it is working fine with the same

Comment: in the above mentioned method , replace all playerVelocity.x with playerVelocity.y and vice-versa.

Comment: Okay let me do that. Will that fix the issue?

Comment: I am guessing it should. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: it is doing reverse behavior all the way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49482/discussion-between-abhineetprasad-and-shivam-s-kara)